# NextJS 13 App Router server side rendering within children

Tags: server-side-rendering, next.js13

I am trying to set up a light/dark mode toggle in my nextjs application. Below are the relevant files

```
app
   -layout.tsx
   -ThemeProvider.tsx


#layout.tsx
import { ThemeProvider } from "./ThemeProvider";
const Layout = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <ThemeProvider>
          <Navbar />
          <main className="px-6">{children}</main>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};

export default Layout;


#ThemeProvider.tsx
"use client"
export const ThemeProvider = ({ children}: {children: ReactNode}) => {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(true);

  return (
    <context.Provider value={{ darkMode, setDarkMode }}>
      <Theme appearance={darkMode ? "dark" : "light"} accentColor="blue">
        {children}
      </Theme>
    </context.Provider>
  );
};
```

Since ThemeProvider is a client component and am I'm wrapping all the children inside, will this turn all the{children} into client components?